# What causes the FuncAnimation func to be called?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, charts

I have an object `A` that instantiates an object `B`, and an object `B` in its constructor does

```
self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.figure, func=self.gen_data, fargs=[self.data_dict],
            blit=True, repeat=False)
```

However, the `self.gen_method` never gets called. What do I do to ensure that this is not the case?

What I ended up doing was putting the above code in a callback that gets triggered in object `A`, which then calls a `refresh()` method on object `B`, but I do not want to keep reconstructing the animation. There should be a way to construct it only once, but how?

So what is the solution, how do I make sure that the `func` gets called regularly?

Comment: where is your `self.gen_method` ??

Comment: It takes a dictionary of data, self.data_dict, and creates plots on the figure.
Its signature is
 def gen_data(self, _, data_dict). The _ is for the index of the frame, which is not used, but passed as argument by default by FuncAnimation.

Comment: All one can say with the little information provided here is that FuncAnimation is constructed correctly. You may want to add the number of frames or a generator as the frames argument, e.g. `frames = 40`, but if that is necessary would depend on the gen_data method.

Comment: I do not have a fixed number of frames. The application keeps populating the data_dict, and I expect the animation to pick up on this and update.

Comment: That's fine. As said it would depend on the function. If it's happy with running continuously, then you don't need the frames argument. Maybe I should mention again what I said for your previous question here: Create a [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: So why is the animation not calling its update func? Any ideas? I tried keeping a reference to the animation in the A object, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using **exactly** your code and working just fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        plt.axis((0,1,0,1))
        self.l1, = plt.plot([],[], color="r")
        self.data_dict = np.random.rand(40,10)
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.figure, func=self.gen_data, fargs=[self.data_dict],
            blit=True, repeat=False)

    def gen_data(self, _, data):
        self.l1.set_data(np.linspace(0,1,10), data[_%40,:])
        return self.l1,

a = A()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Actually, A creates B in A's constructor, and B creates the animation in its own constructor. Could you please try something like that?

Comment: There is no reason why this shouldn't work but I updated the answerto have A creating B.